# Pytest session scoped fixture yields multiple times - help me understand

Tags: python, pytest, yield

Below is an example of a pytest session and function scoped fixtures.

The first fixture sets up a single db connection, whilst the second one deletes the DB state to have a clean slate for each test function.

My understanding of the `yield` in the session scoped fixture is wonky. I thought yield gives control over to testing functions once and then continues with tear down. But if we mix up function scoped fixture that depends on the session scope fixture, it keeps re-using the same instance of the db, implying `yield` is yielding control multiple times (however does not create the db multiple times). This is confusing to me. Can you help me out here with understanding this?

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def db():
    """CardsDB object connected to a temporary database"""
    with TemporaryDirectory() as db_dir:
        db_path = Path(db_dir)
        db_ = cards.CardsDB(db_path)
        yield db_
        db_.close()

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def cards_db(db):
    """CardsDB object that's empty"""
    db.delete_all()
    return db
```

Comment: It must be the case that pytest saves the session scoped db reference and passes to the function scoped fixture in this case and yield does only yield once

Comment: So what is your problem? You just want to understand how fixtures are implemented? You can always check the [pytest source code](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/main/src/_pytest/fixtures.py), `_FixtureCachedResult` may be what you are looking for.

Comment: that sounds along the lines of what I expect it to do, yeah